# What is the comparative and superlative form of "super"?

Tags: comparative-constructions, superlatives

I need a little help about how to form comparative and superlative degree for the word "super". I found on a website as *supe*r is used for comparative and superlative degree as well. And I also learnt from some other source that an adjective with two or more syllables usually takes *more* and *most* for comparative and superlative.

Comment: Even some ***one-*** syllable words don't normally take the ***-er, -est*** suffixes (***deader*** and ***deadest*** are unlikely). There's certainly the facetious [***more betterer***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22more+betterer%22), but I don't think ***superer*** and ***superest*** would occur very often at all. There are very few contexts where it would make sense to use ***more super***, but people say *We had the **most super** time!* all the time!

Comment: (Note that it's not idiomatic in English to say that *X is **more** super than Y*, or that *X is **the most** super*.)

Comment: Can you please link that website you're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

The options would be "more super", "superer", "most super", and "superest".
 Looking at Google ngram for historical uses of any of those, I don't find any valid uses.
[Google Ngram super forms](https://tinyurl.com/ybdnjarp)
 There are some false hits for cases like "more super-important" and "more Super Bowl rings", and "superest" in Latin texts, a conjugated verb.

If I had to use such a form, I would use "more super" and "most super", but I would expect to sound strange.
The word "super" doesn't seem to have been used much in comparative or superlative form, maybe because it already has a superlative connotation.
"That is super!" is similar in meaning to "That is the best!", where "best" is already a superlative.

Comment: Definitely it's non-gradable, it's an extreme adjective

Comment: It could be used in a humorous way: *That Alan, he's the **most super** superintendent I've ever known.* But that's certainly an edge case, and it's only humorous because it's *not* normally used like that. (And, more traditionally anyway, it would likely be: *That Alan, he puts the **super** into superintendent.*)